# Telephone Directory: dividing code/making menu

Tags: c++

I am making a Telephone Directory. Now, as someone said dividing code in small section is a better code. I want to make it something like, but the problem is I can't access the object from main function to a class's member function or a traditional function. I am not sure how pass an object (arrays of objects) as a parameter (to a function).

```
case 2:
{
      print_header("Update Menu");
      print_update_menu();
      break;
```

*This is my code:-*

```
 case 2:
                Print_Header("Update Menu");
                while (1)
                {
                    cout<<"Please enter a Name or ID to Update:"<<endl;

                    cin>>search_ID_name;
                    for(int j=0 ; j<=records-1 ; j++)
                    {
                        if((search_ID_name==Telephone_directory[j].ID) || (search_ID_name==Telephone_directory[j].Name) )
                        {
                            Telephone_directory[j].Phone_Directory_data_display();
                            cout<<"Do you want to update this record? [1/0]"<<endl;
                            cin>>choice;
                            if(choice==1)
                            {
                                Telephone_directory[j].Phone_Directory_data_input();
                                cout<<"Record successfully updated"<<endl;
                                Telephone_directory[j].Phone_Directory_data_display();
                            }
                            else if (choice==0)
                            {
                                cout<<"Record not updated"<<endl;
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    cout<<"Want to update another record? [y/n]"<<endl;
                    cin>>choice_y_n;
                    if(choice_y_n=='y')
                    {
                        cout<<"Redirecting to Update Menu again"<<endl;
                    }
                    else if (choice_y_n=='n')
                        break;
                }
                break;
```

Comment: ***Now, as someone said dividing code in small section is a better code*** Yes you may want to should call a function in your `case 2:` instead of that block of code.

Comment: Please show what a `Telephone_directory` is.

Comment: Telephone_directory is an object. Of class Phone_Directory

Comment: I think that what @drescherjm meant was that you should show us the `Phone_Directory` _code_ - at least its definition. Better yet, make a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

In C++ there are two ways to pass an object to a function.

- Pass by value (copy)
- Pass by pointer (reference to memory location)

Of these you usually pass by reference for objects.

If you want to pass an object of type `A` to a function called `f` you would do it like so:

```cpp
void f(A& a) {
  // You can access a's members here i.e if a has a method called b you do a.b();
}
```

Comment: how will we call it in the main function? Can you please tell me it's syntax too?

Comment: In the above example it would be a.member_func() but you really need to look this up as there are _many_ rules governing object member access